# incrementation inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
(...)
'choices' => array(
    $new_array['font-css'][0] => $new_array['font-name'][0]
)
```

In `new_array['font-name']` there are font names.

**I need to display all font names**, but the new_array['font-name'] is array and to get one font name, I must use `new_array['font-name'][0]` (first font), or `[1]`(second font).

The same problem for with $new_array['font-css']. I must display all css names.

I can't use `foreach()` and for() inside the array. and I can't increment variable.

Is there way to attach to array all font names from `$new_array['font-name']` and all css name from `$new_array['font-css']`? Maybe, is there any way to increment a variable inside an array?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this is what you were asking for:-

```
// example array
$new_array = array();
$new_array['font-css'] = array('blue', 'red', 'green');
$new_array['font-name'] = array('tahoma', 'arial', 'verdana');

$choices = array();
foreach ($new_array['font-css'] as $k => $v) {
    $choices[$v] = $new_array['font-name'][$k];
}

var_dump($choices);
```

So loop through your `font-css` array, and map the value of each to the corresponding value in the `font-name` array, each to an array named `$choices`.

The above example outputs:-

```
array
  'blue' => string 'tahoma' (length=6)
  'red' => string 'arial' (length=5)
  'green' => string 'verdana' (length=7)
```

Which is essentially the same as:-

```
'choices' => array(
    $new_array['font-css'][0] => $new_array['font-name'][0],
    $new_array['font-css'][1] => $new_array['font-name'][1],
    $new_array['font-css'][2] => $new_array['font-name'][2]
);
```